# How to add a field in login form in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, login

I have added a drop down field in registration form.
Now i want to add this field in login form,I tried to do in login.phtml but it is not showing
anything.

Can anyone please suggest..

Comment: what did you try ? show the code

Comment: I tried to add dropdown field inapp/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml but nothing is showing in the frontend

Comment: may be you are using different `package/theme` directory. Use template path hints as mentioned my @Marius. It will show exactly which template file login page uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 templates that are used for login in Magento.
one in `customer/form/login.phtml` and one in `persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`.
If you have persistent cart enabled then the second one will be used.
Try to add your field in there.

As a general thing, you can always view what template file is used by turning on the [template path hints](http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/)

Comment: For curiosity.. Is there any reason why Magento uses a different login template for persistant cart ?

Comment: I have the same curiosity. My suspicious is that at first this was supposed to be an enterprise package and they created it separately, but decided later to include it in CE also and they just changed the namespace. But I may be wrong.

Comment: there is a `form.additional.info` (childhtml) in both template files (persistent/customer) but this seems not working when persistent is enabled. i used that handle to add custom html without overriding core. I'll put my answer after figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have used `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml` and you can't see any changes in frontend. Then the reason would be you may use a custom theme for your site. If `package/theme` of your site is different and that theme holds a `login.phtml` template, then Magento will use that `login.phtml` instead of `base/default` 's `login.phtml`.

In order to find which template login page uses, as Marius suggested you can use template hints. You can activate template hints through `System  >  Configuration   > Developer`.

An another way would be go to `System  >  Configuration  >  Design`. There you can find which package and theme your system currently using. Then go to the location `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/customer/form/` and check whether there exists `login.phtml`. If it exists then that is the file that you need to alter. Else you need to copy paste`base/default` 's `login.phtml` and paste there. Then edit that file. This will ensure core files untouched.